# How to fix "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" in Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I am getting following error,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

I am trying to fetch data from the database and make a model in the Angular to save the data of the same.

I have tried to make the models but it fails.

Here the loadConversation function fetches the data from the database. And the rest are the models which tries to save the data.

```
    loadConversation() {
        this.conversationsService.get('http://172.26.90.49:9000/api/v1/conversation/conversation/?conversation_id=1')
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.conversation = new Conversation(res);
          });
      }


    export class Conversation {

        title: string;
        final_conclusion_message: string;
        gender: string;
        dialogs!: Dialog[];


        constructor(data: any) {
            data = data || {};

            this.title = data.title;
            this.final_conclusion_message = data.final_conclusion_message;
            this.gender = data.gender;
            this.dialogs = [];
            data.dialog_options.forEach((q: any) => {
                this.dialogs.push(new Dialog(q));
            });
        }



    }

export class Dialog {
    id!: number;
    message!: string;
    dialog_images!: any[];
    dialog_has_options!: DialogOptions[];


    constructor(data: any) {
        data = data || {};
        this.id = data.id;
        this.message = data.message;
        this.dialog_images = data.dialog_images;
        this.dialog_has_options = [];
        data.dialog_has_options.forEach((q: any) => {
            this.dialog_has_options.push(new DialogOptions(q));
        });



    }



}


export class DialogOptions {
    option!: {
        id: number;
        message: string;
        option_images: any;
    };
    upcoming_dialog!: number;
    wrong_option_message!: string;
    loopback!: boolean;
    is_last!: boolean;

    constructor(data: any) {
        data = data || {};

        this.option.id = data.option.id;
        this.option.message = data.option.message;
        this.option.option_images = data.option.option_images;
        this.upcoming_dialog = data.upcoming_dialog;
        this.wrong_option_message = data.wrong_option_message;
        this.loopback = data.loopback;
        this.is_last = data.is_last;

    }

}
```

I want to resolve the error.

Comment: Your `data` doesn't have a `dialog_options` property. You fix it by either supplying it or guarding against that possibility.

Comment: My data has dialog_options property. I have checked it in the data base.

Comment: Yet for one reason or another, it doesn't come through *or* your `data` is falsey when it arrives, so `data = data || {}` will assign an empty object to it. Whatever it is, you should do more debugging yourself here.

Comment: It is resolved. Apparently, when I send data it doesn't work. If I break up the data into individual parts in the constructor it works.